# What is the difference between aws-codepipeline/Pipeline and pipelines/CodePipelines in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have an AWS CDK project and am defining a code pipeline with the CDK to automatically deploy it.

Should I use the CodePipeline defined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html

or the Pipeline defined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.Pipeline.html

Also what exactly is the difference between the two?

Edit: I linked to the wrong doc for Pipeline. I've updated the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`aws-codepipeline.Pipeline`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.Pipeline.html) is an L2 construct for the AWS CodePipeline resource.

[`pipelines.CodePipeline`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html) is part of the [CDK pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html) module that is a higher-level abstraction for deploying CDK apps. Under the hood, it uses `aws-codepipeline.Pipeline` for its pipelines, but there are also other implementations ([with GitHub Actions, for example](https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-pipelines-github)), since the `pipelines.CodePipeline` API was meant to be an abstract API (the naming is unfortunate, though). Further reading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html